# CSS limited background repeat (multiple background images)

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to make a cool background effect (with alpha transparency and rounded corners) for a drop-down menu with a single CSS entry.

I have a top cap (180 x 4 px), a bottom cap (180 x 20px) and a repeating middle (180 x 2px).

Here is my existing relevant CSS:

```
background-image: url('images/drop_top.png'), url('images/drop_bottom.png'), url('images/drop_middle.png');
background-position:left top, left bottom, 0px 10px;
background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-y;
```

The problem is that the middle section which needs to be expandable/tilable is repeating all the way under the top and bottom caps--such that my rounded corners are now square because they have the repeating middle under them.

Is there some way to prevent the multiple backgrounds from overlapping??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using the multiple backgrounds property, why not just use `border-radius`?

Comment: I'm using a fancy-schmancy shadow effect at the bottom (not a css-one)

Comment: I've never used it, so I don't know if it'll work, but maybe `background-clip`? http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-border-background-boxshadow/#background-clip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Background-origin and/or background-clip](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/) should do the trick. Just set top & bottom borders equal to the height of your cap graphics, then set drop_middle to `background-clip:padding-box`

---

EDIT: Here is a complete solution, but for a horizontal orientation:
http://jsfiddle.net/nGSba/

```
#box
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 9px;
    border-left:9px solid transparent;
    border-right:9px solid transparent;
    background-image: url(http://s11.postimage.org/ufpdknvjz/left.png), 
          url(http://s11.postimage.org/6ng294tj3/right.png),
          url(http://www.css3.info/wp-content/themes/new_css3/img/main.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
    background-position: left top, right top, left top;
    background-origin: border-box,border-box,padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box,border-box,padding-box;
}
```

What got me stuck was the `transparent` on the `border-color`. The background will always go *under* the border, so if your border is solid the background will still be invisible.

Comment: This is what I'm using and its still overlapping:  border-top-width:4px;
 border-bottom-width:19px;
 background-image: url('images/drop_top.png'), url('images/drop_bottom.png'), url('images/drop_middle.png');
 background-position:left top, left bottom, 0px 10px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-y;
 background-clip:border-box, border-box, padding-box;

Comment: It seems that both `background-origin` AND `background-clip` must be set for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your element is that you are applying the images to, try doing the following (I'll assume `div` for sake of illustration):

```
div {
    background-image: url('images/drop_top.png'), url('images/drop_bottom.png');
    background-position:left top, left bottom;
    background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

div:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px ; /* whatever your top image height is */
    bottom: 10px; /* whatever your bottom image height is */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url('images/drop_middle.png');
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: Just curious if this would be a cross browser solution, considering IE is a mess.

Comment: Have not tested, but any older browser not recognizing `:after` pseudoelement it would not work on.